# Filter by languages in 2nd and 4th level keys of a couchdb document

Tags: internationalization, filter, couchdb

Given the following document in CouchDB....

```
{
   "_id": "002bafd55b353692a7ab2968074310cc2cbff258",
   "_rev": "1-bc853056ac61d817ae3c4ecb4f81322b",
   "names": [
     { "locale": "en", "value": "Example"  },
     { "locale": "de", "value": "Beispiel" },
     { "locale": "fr", "value": "Exemple"  }
   ],
   "details": [
     { "locale": "en", "value": "An Example is here" },
     { "locale": "de", "value": "Ein Beispiel ist heir" }
     { "locale": "en", "value": "Un exemple est ici" }
   ]
}
```

...how can I write a *view* that will allow me to return a partial document with
the undesired languages filtered out?

- **`curl ..snip.. '_design/locale_filter/?locale=en,de,fr,it'`**
- **`curl ..snip.. '_design/locale_filter/?locale=en,fr'`**
- **`curl ..snip.. '_design/locale_filter/?locale=en'`**

Should return something looking like this:

```
{
   "_id": "002bafd55b353692a7ab2968074310cc2cbff258",
   "_rev": "1-bc853056ac61d817ae3c4ecb4f81322b",
   "names": [
     { "locale": "en", "value": "Example"  },
   ],
   "details": [
     { "locale": "en", "value": "An Example is here" },
   ]
}
```

There's also a sub-case, where the documents have a further deeper structure,
which repeats the *names* and *details* structure, these would also be
filtered in an ideal world:

```
{
   "_id": "002bafd55b353692a7ab2968074310cc2cbff258",
   "_rev": "1-bc853056ac61d817ae3c4ecb4f81322b",
   "names": [ ... snip ... ],
   "details": [ ... snip ... ]
   "deeper": {
      "names": [
         { "locale": "en", "value": "Sub-Example"  },
      ],
      "details": [
         { "locale": "en", "value": "The Sub-Example is here" },
    }
}
```

I also note that this might not be a ***view***, but rather a *show*, from the
documentation couchdb says that a show is for transforming documents into any
format.

The final query from a beginner is whether there's some way to make it easier
to work on couchdb views and design docs, right now I'm experimenting with
[*erica*](https://github.com/benoitc/erica) which feels like overkill as I'm
pretty sure I don't want a couch app, I just want to easily maintain my views
in files on the disk, and sync them with the couch database whenever I've made
significant enough changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement this using a [*show function*](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/show.html), I implemented two show functions, one for convenience:

```
(doc, req) ->
  all_locales = []
  for name in doc.names
    all_locales.push name.locale
  toJSON(all_locales)
```

(I also implemented it on `details`, and remove duplicate locales in my real code)

This allows me to do the following:

```
GET /_design/dbname/_show/list_locales/c0db9ad..snip..
```

and returns `["en", "de", "fr"]`, for example - whatever locales the language happens to have.

I can then follow up with the function to retrieve the filtered document:

```
(doc, req) ->
  locales = req.query.locales.split(",")
  doc.names = doc.names.filter (name) ->
    locales.indexOf(name.locale) > -1
  doc.overviews = doc.details.filter (overview) ->
    locales.indexOf(overview.locale) > -1
  return toJSON(doc) + "\n"
```

The usage pattern for this is:

```
GET /_design/dbname/_show/restrict_locales/c0db9ad..snip..?locales=en,fr
GET /_design/dbname/_show/restrict_locales/c0db9ad..snip..?locales=fr
GET /_design/dbname/_show/restrict_locales/c0db9ad..snip..?locales=en,fr,de,it,hu,zh
```

It works quite remarkably well, and was much faster than I expected. I believe the show function results are aggressively cached by CouchDB.